# Ingress-nginx returning 503 to app-root path

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have deployed ingress nginx controller using this [Ingress-Nginx-Doc](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/) to Aws EKS Cluster

**Issue:**

```
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  namespace: mynamespace
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTP"
spec:
  - path: /
      backend:
        serviceName: my-app
        servicePort: 7300
```

when I access my app. http://load-balancer-url/ nginx throwing 503.

```
[27/May/2020:15:27:40 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 503 600 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36" 662 0.000 [namespace-serviceName-7300] [] - - - - 21eb2db883548292ce20a71ddf45df99
W0527 15:39:07.037844       6 controller.go:909] Service "mynamespace/service" does not have any active Endpoint.
```

Am I missing any annotations?

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-app
  labels:
    app: my-app
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - protocol : TCP
      port: 7300
      targetPort: 7300
  selector:
    name: my-app
    namespace: my-namespace
```

Comment: share output of kubectl describe svc my-app

Comment: `Name:              my-app
Namespace:         my-namespace
Labels:            app=myname
Annotations:       Selector:  name=my-app,namespace=mynamespace
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                172.20.26.*
Port:              <unset>  7300/TCP
TargetPort:        7300/TCP
Endpoints:         <none>
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>`

Comment: share the service and pod yaml in question by editing it not in the comments

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu Shared

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is the service `my-app` has `none` in the `Endpoints` section which should have IPs of the pods.

Referring from [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/#does-the-service-have-any-endpoints) you should check that the `spec.selector` field of your service actually selects for `metadata.labels` values on your Pods. A common mistake is to have a typo or other error, such as the service selecting for `name=my-app`, but the Deployment specifying something else.